# concatenating class labels with different size

Tags: matlab, label, dimensions

I have **different class labels, for different cases**. I want to concatenate the class labels for all of the cases in one vector. the class labels have different size and they have char type.

for example I have **10** cases, each have **5** class labels, and class labels are: **a,ab,cd,fgh,khgld**. how can I do that? (I need it to be vetroized in each case and finally vectorized for all of cases. so it will be **50*1** (is it possible to have only 1 column contrary to differnet size of labels))

because of having different sizes the concateting is impossible, I used cell too do this, but the result was not correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your expected output? does `C = {'a','ab','cd','fgh','khgld'};` => `S = string(C);` helps you?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Thanks for your suggestion. And one question, because class labels will not have the same length, in this method we have the labels with the largest length. in this example are off them will be in this format: ['a    ', 'ab   ','cd   ', 'fgh  ','khgld']. I think this will make some problems? Am I right?(I mean because for example, a is one charcater , this function adds 4 more spaces until we have the same length as others)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: let me rephrase it. I have 5 class labels as mentioned above. this class labels are in cell format. I want to put them in a vector. so I need that they have the same size. this function **string** adds spaces to the labels that don't have length=5 (5, because khgld has 5 chars.), for example to label a. I want to know if this spaces are important or not?

Comment: no. `string` converts them to a string array (which is **not** char array)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @user2999345 , I want to run my code in another system, and now the problem is that, it gives me the error : **undefined function string for input argument of type char**. what can be the reason?the version of MATLAB?

Comment: that was because of my MATLAB version!! But what can it be replaced by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added spaces to each string which is shorter than the longest:

```
c = {'sas','as','tttttt'};
s = max(cellfun('size',c,2));
c = cellfun(@(str) [str,repmat(' ',[1 s - numel(str)])],c,'UniformOutput',0);
m = cell2mat(c')
```